How do I set the max/min/fixed length rules for the string field?
I know Django ninja schema uses the Pydantic model, how do I set the max/min/fixed length rules for the string field?
  class TestSchema(Schema):
    name1: str[length=6]
    name2: str[maxlength=6]
    name3: str[minlength=6]



Use constr instead str:
from ninja import Schema
from pydantic import constr

class TestSchema(Schema):
    name1: constr(min_length=6, max_length=6)
    name2: constr(max_length=6)
    name3: constr(min_length=6)


Thanks.  I have posted the latest setting pattern for this case according to the official website note. Because constr function is discouraged in favor of using Annotated with StringConstraints instead.

Refer to the Oliverira's answer. I searched the constr on the Pydantic website.
Below is the note:
This function is discouraged in favor of using Annotated with StringConstraints instead.
This function will be deprecated in Pydantic 3.0.
The suggested way:

from typing_extensions import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, StringConstraints

class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Annotated[
        str,
        StringConstraints(
            strip_whitespace=True, to_upper=True, pattern=r'^[A-Z]+$'
        ),
    ]


For my case:
 name1: Annotated[
        str,
        StringConstraints(
            min_length=6, max_length=6
        ),
    ]


